# How do I convince my Firewall that my request isn't an SQL injection attack?

Tags: php, sql-injection, form-submit, firewall

I built one application in core php which is hosted on IIS server and windows 8 PC. WAF security is added on this application.

When I submit the page/form with details like this "Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text" , WAF is blocking this request before executing server side code. I use PDO using Parameterized queries and also CRF token. Still request get blocked. Looks like it is blocking those request where there is word like "is not", "and","or" etc sql keyword. I have created below test page.

```
<? 
    $FAILED=false;
    $MSG='';

    if(isset($_POST['add_review']))
    {

        $FAILED=false;
        $MSG='Data submitted';
        echo $MSG; exit;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="frm-add-review" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="review_id" value="<?=@intval($_GET['id'])?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?=generateCSRFtoken('add_review')?>">
            <textarea name="txt_review" id="txt_review"></textarea>
            <div class="form-actions">
                button type="submit" id="add_review" name="add_review" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>

            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: What happens when you turn the firewall off? As a temporary test case.

Comment: @GetSet : If i turnoff the WAF then request is submitted successfully.

Comment: Possibly you could add an exception to the firewall if its coming from your server?

Comment: Sounds to me like your query is missing some escapes. Normally a string can't animate a WAF to this behaviour. This is only possible if the words in a string could get to the same tier as the normal commands. Maybe you can show us your query?

Comment: @kreya Which "WAF" exactly have you added and what configuration have you added to it. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of the "WAF" you are using and the configuration/settings you are using.